# Manually group DataGrid items

Tags: wpf, datagrid, grouping

I need to use a data grid and my data looks as follows:
firstName, lastName, street, zip, city, country, image

In my datagrid I will only show firstName, lastName and image but it has to be grouped after city.

**Update**
The code below shows grouped items but the three items I want to display (firstName, lastName, image) are followed by all items (firstName, lastName, street, zip, city, country, image) per row. I think I have to replace the `<ItemsPresenter />` but thats only speculation..

Can anyone help me, I can't manage this on my own...

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedMovables}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Preview" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Name="Preview" Height="20" Source="{Binding Image}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="first name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="last name" Binding="{Binding LastName}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=City}" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="3"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Expander>
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}" Margin="8,0,4,0"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text="Element(s)"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please elaborate: what isn't working, exactly? Does the code produce an error? If so, what's the error? Does it display incorrectly? If so, how does it display now, and how does that differ from what you want? Thanks.

Comment: I updated my explanation, hope its clearer now.

Comment: And what happens if you remove `<ItemsPresenter />`?

Comment: Please check my answer below and compare it to your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper way for grouping is to use a `CollectionView` (for more details: [How to Navigate, Group, Sort and Filter Data in WPF](http://www.wpftutorial.net/dataviews.html#grouping)). The following is a simple proof of concept application I created for you to show you how to use a `CollectionView` for grouping you data:

This class represents a row in the DataGrid:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

MaindWindow code behind:

```
    /// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Create some test data
        var employees =
            new ObservableCollection<Employee>
                {
                    new Employee {FirstName = "Mohammed", LastName = "Fadil", Street = "A B C", ZipCode = "123", City = "London", Country = "UK", Image = "/Images/globe.png"},
                    new Employee {FirstName = "Siraj", LastName = "Hussam", Street = "A B C", ZipCode = "123", City = "London", Country = "UK", Image = "/Images/globe.png"},
                    new Employee {FirstName = "Ayman", LastName = "Tariq", Street = "A B C", ZipCode = "123", City = "London", Country = "UK", Image = "/Images/globe.png"},
                    new Employee {FirstName = "Khalid", LastName = "Sheik", Street = "X Y Z", ZipCode = "234", City = "Paris", Country = "France", Image = "/Images/monitor.png"},
                    new Employee {FirstName = "Hassan", LastName = "Ali", Street = "Q W E R", ZipCode = "544", City = "NY", Country = "USA", Image = "/Images/star.png"},
                    new Employee {FirstName = "Ehsan", LastName = "Mahmoud", Street = "A B C", ZipCode = "123", City = "London", Country = "UK", Image = "/Images/globe.png"},
                    new Employee {FirstName = "Idris", LastName = "Sheik", Street = "X Y Z", ZipCode = "234", City = "Paris", Country = "France", Image = "/Images/monitor.png"},
                    new Employee {FirstName = "Khalil", LastName = "Ali", Street = "Q W E R", ZipCode = "544", City = "NY", Country = "USA", Image = "/Images/star.png"}
                };

        ICollectionView employeesView =
            CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(employees);

        // Set the grouping by city proprty
        employeesView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("City"));

        // Set the view as the DataContext for the DataGrid
        EmployeesDataGrid.DataContext = employeesView;
    }
}
```

The DataGrid XAML code:

```
    <DataGrid Name="EmployeesDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirstName}" Header="First Name"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastName}" Header="Last Name"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=City}" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="3"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Expander>
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}" Margin="8,0,4,0"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text="Element(s)"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>

    </DataGrid>
```

The result is:

[image: Result]

For more information about styling the DataGrid groups please check this post: [WPF DataGrid Control > Grouping](http://www.wpftutorial.net/datagrid.html#grouping)

Comment: The example from wpftutorial.net you posted was the one I used. I'm not sure about what I did wrong but the code you provided runs as I wanted it to do, thank you very much!

Comment: @iop, try to run my posted code in a new sample project, it works fine.

Comment: @iop, check the output window when you run this window to see if there is problems with your binding to 'GroupedMovables'

Comment: Why header template is not appeared on output?